# Bounty on another person's question with my own answer

Tags: discussion

I offered a bounty on another person's question because I was facing exactly the same issue: [Visual Studio 2013 Error: workflow "could not generate view for item"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118434/visual-studio-2013-error-workflow-could-not-generate-view-for-item).

In the meantime, I came up with the solution and posted it as an answer. My concern is, who gets rewarded for a bounty? Obviously, I cannot award myself so it's a pity to waste bounty reward. Theoretically, someone could literally copy my answer and earn bounty reward. This seems like a perfectly legitimate thing to do. What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

It's always tricky when you answer your own bounty question. You can't get the bounty points back, and in theory another user can copy your answer, receive a minimum of +2 votes and get half the bounty if you don't award the full bounty.

> This is accepted behavior and has been detailed in the FAQ topics concerning bounties. If you answer your own bounty you are not eligible for getting the bounty back.
>
> Basically the only way the bounty will get awarded to anybody is:
>
> You accept an answer during the bounty period.
>
> If the bounty period expires, the highest voted answer (minimum score of +2) wins half the bounty.
>
> If there is a tie on answers with minimum score of +2, the first answer is accepted.
>
> Any other scenario and you will lose the reputation and no reputation will be awarded to anybody else.

Ref: [Accepted answer on the Question "Lost reputation after answering my own question with bounty {duplicate}"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18845/180230)